# How can I horizontally align the following header image?

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I have tried the whole afternoon but I'm missing something, can some one help me with this?
The page can be found at the following link

[The page with the image that I need fixed](http://www.websu.it/tv-film/hello-world/).

The code containing the image is:

```
    <headerimage><span>
            <img width="1920" height="600" src="http://www.websu.it/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/suitsheader.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Suits Header" title="Suits Header"></span>
        </headerimage>
```

I would like to horizontally center the image with a width of 1920px on smaller screens. When I give a class the property background-position: top center, it works perfectly, but when I need to have a -tag in the page itself I can't seem to make it happen.

Please help me see it :) It's probably very stupid, haha.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `margin: 0 auto;` on the image, like:

```
<headerimage>
  <span>
    <img style="margin:0 auto;" width="1920" height="600" src="http://www.websu.it/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/suitsheader.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Suits Header" title="Suits Header">
  </span>
</headerimage>
```

Comment: Hey Andy, thanks for your response. It doesn't work however, probably because I did something weird in the CSS. Would you mind checking out the [page](http://www.websu.it/tv-film/hello-world/)? Perhaps you can find out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: @RobinPapa Oh you want the center of the image to constantly be on the screen, and the image to always be 1920px wide? That's not possible with only CSS

Comment: Well not exactly: I use images larger than screen-width, often 1920px, so that the image can be shown at 100% screen width on a large variety of screens. I just need it to be horizontally centered all the time, so that I see the center 1440 pixels on my 1440px screen, for example. Using margin:0 auto just doesn't work :/.

You are right though, that's what I try to establish, just not with 1920px but simply the image's full size.

Comment: Just apply `width: 100%` to the image then, it will always be as wide as the screen then

Comment: Disregard, Thanks man! That did it! Thought I already tried that haha, thanks a lot!

Comment: But I cheered too soon... That fits the width of the image to the width of the screen, but that's not what I needed. I need the image to be fullsized and then centered in the viewport of 100%.

Comment: @RobinPapa Then what I would recommend is media queries. Centering a huge image on smaller resolutions will look extremely silly. Do a rule for anything above 1920 px (wide enough to fit image) set the image to margin: 0 auto;, anything under that, set width to 100% so it fills the screen

Comment: I agree with you, that is indeed a better solution. Thank you for your insights!

Answer (score 1):

I would not put this in as an image but as a background on your header.

```
background-image:url('http://www.websu.it/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/suitsheader.jpg');
background-position-x:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/dwat001/Q58YZ/ for a rough demonstration.

Comment: Hey David, thanks a lot! Unfortunately, in my original design I did use this fix, but I'm stuck with Wordpress and retrieving the image from the "featured image"-section of the blog post. So I need to use the img tag. Can you help me further? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach if you cannot use background-image is to use javascript to position the image.

```
<style>
  #imageHolder {
    overflow: hidden; // if image is bigger then holder, clip the image, no scollbars.
  }

  #wideHeaderImage {
    position: relative; // treat "left" as relative to the images normal position.
  }
</style>
<headerimage id="imageHolder">
  <img id="wideHeaderImage" width="1920".../>
</headerimage>

<script src="jquery"></script>
<script>
  // create function to center image;
  var centerImage = function($) {
     var windowWidth = $(window).width(); // get the current width of the window
     var imageSize = $('#wideHeaderImage').width(); // get width of image                                             
     $('#imageHolder').width(windowWidth); // set the containing element to be size of window.
     if(imageSize > windowWidth) { // if image is wider then window
       var offset = (imageSize - windowWidth) / 2; // Establish an offset
       $('#wideHeaderImage').css('left', '-' + offset + 'px'); // apply offset
     }
  };

  jquery(function($) {
    // this code runs within on load

    // register a resize event handler
    $(window).resize(function(event){centerImage($);});
    // resize once on onload.
    centerImage($);
  });
</script>
```

I have not run this so I've problably made some mistakes hopefully enough for you to get the gist of what I'm doing.

Comment: Much appreciated, will have to test this another time! Thanks a lot!